# I want to return all documents with query {guardian:g_id, student: s_id} sorting them in descending order but its not working out

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, find

I want to return all documents with query {guardian:g_id, student: s_id} sorting them in descending order but it only returns the document i entered first.

```
const old_payments = await paymentsSchema.find({guardian: g_id, student: s_id },{sort: { updatedAt: -1 }})
```

i expect an array "old_payments" containing docs of payments with those specific guardian and student ids sorted in decending order using the updatedAt field.

Comment: How are you determining that only one document is being retrieved? Also, have you double checked that more than one document matches the query filter?